# Partition Based on Date is Problematic for Table's Primary Key - Any Workaround?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that I would like to partition based on the "deleted" date.

```
create table resources(
        id int,
        type varchar(30),
        deleted date
)
```

I want to have a foreign key from another table pointing to this table's id column.  However since I have the partition based on the deleted date, I must include it in the primary key.  Adding the deleted column to the primary key does not make sense and will also prevent the other table's FK from pointing to this table.  Is there a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: What about a check constraint?  It's far from ideal, but it should do the job

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no workaround for foreign keys to a partitioned table. You have to add `deleted` to the primary key or unique constraint and also to the table that references the partitioned table.

If you don't want that, you'll have to go without a foreign key constraint.

Perhaps it would be useful to add `deleted` to the referencing table and partition that along the same boundaries as `resources`. Then you could get rid of old data in a coordinated fashion, and if you add `deleted` to the join condition, you can profit from `enable_partitionwise_join = on`.